# How to show that two operators in the forms of vectors commute?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, commutator, lie-algebra

[image]

This is an exercise from Peskin&Schroeder's book. The exercise requires to show that $\textbf{J+}$ and $\textbf{J-}$ commute with each other. What is the exact meaning of commutation between operators that are the form of vectors? Do I have to just show that $[\textbf{J+}^i, \textbf{J-}^i]=0$? Or do I have to show that $[\textbf{J+}^i, \textbf{J-}^j]=0$? I am confused...

Comment: Are you confusing 'vector operator' (i.e. an operator that acts on vectors) with 'operator that is a vector'?

Comment: I mean the latter.

Comment: You have  to show that each component of the first vector commutes with each component of the second.

Answer (score 1):

in this specific case you have to show that 
$$[J_+^i,J_-^j]=0$$
meaning that every component commutes with every component.

Comment: Only in this specific case? How about general cases?

Comment: The above relation is more general than $[J_+^i,J_-^i]=0$.